# redirect index page to index page with anchor appended to it in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

htaccess redirection and would like to redirect all visitors on (domain.com, domain.com/,domain.com/index.php ) to www.domain.com/index.php#block_1 . below is my rules in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301] 

RewriteRule index\.php index.php#block_1 [NE]
```

i keep getting error 500, Some one point what im doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the error is because you're specifying an **internal** (Non-HTTP) redirect, which happens to send apache into a redirect loop.

Try:

```
RewriteRule index\.php index.php#block_1 [NE,R]
```

Because browsers never send the anchor part of the URL string to the server, you cannot test for it, so this will likely cause an infinite HTTP redirect loop for the client.

You will likely have to redirect to a second page, like this.

```
RewriteRule index\.php otherpage.php#block_1 [NE,R]
```

The [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) explains it all.

Comment: Is that good? Bad? I will re-iterate: you will not be able to use the same page for the source and target of this redirection, due to the nature of the redirection you are trying to do.

Comment: ive got that but i mean, it redirects and appends the relative path of the url ie /var/www/html/'

Comment: I'm not sure, but you could try adding a slash: `RewriteRule index\.php /otherpage.php#block_1 [NE,R]`. If you're the server admin you could [enable the RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) temporarily to see what's going on

Answer (score 0):

To escape the "#", try \%23 with an [NE,L] flag on the rule.

```
RewriteRule index\.php index.php\%23block_1 [NE,L]
```

Comment: Look at the reply by @Lethargy \%23 is the correct way to escape # in .htaccess.

Comment: Since #block_1 is only treated by the web browser you should use Javascript to force the browser to focus on #block_1 when the page has loaded.

Comment: i use javascript to force a page redirection? how would i cause javascript to behave well without a refresh?